# Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect at Navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this bugging error anytime I log out from my app. I'm using Redux toolkit for my state management. It was working perfectly until I added redux persist to my app.
[My console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YYAr.png)
I really have no idea what's triggering it. I'm saving the user to the cookies so that when the cookie expires, the user would be redirected back to the login page. ( This is an amateur work and I'm still looking for the best way to perform this but I digress). What could be triggering this error?

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Navigate,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { persistor, store } from "./app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ProtectedRoutes from "./utils/ProtectedRoutes";
import NotFound from "./views/Dashboard/Settings/NotFound";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <Router>
        <Suspense fallback={<LazyLoad />}>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
              <Route path={`admin/*`} element={<AdminLayout />} />
              <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/admin/dashboard" />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path={`auth/*`} element={<AuthLayout />} />
          </Routes>
        </Suspense>
      </Router>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

ProtectedRoutes.jsx

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from "js-cookie"

export default function ProtectedRoutes() {

  let userid = Cookies.get("user") == null ? false : true;
  return <div>{userid ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/auth/login" />}</div>;
}
```

The logout function

```
const logout = async () => {
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_LOCAL_URL}/api/v1/auth/logout`
  );

  if (response.data) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
    sessionStorage.removeItem("user");
    localStorage.removeItem("apiEnv");
  }
  return response.data;
};
```

I have this bugging error anytime I log out from my app. I'm using Redux toolkit for my state management. It was working perfectly until I added redux persist to my app.
[My console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YYAr.png)
I really have no idea what's triggering it. I'm saving the user to the cookies so that when the cookie expires, the user would be redirected back to the login page. ( This is an amateur work and I'm still looking for the best way to perform this but I digress). What could be triggering this error?

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Navigate,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { persistor, store } from "./app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ProtectedRoutes from "./utils/ProtectedRoutes";
import NotFound from "./views/Dashboard/Settings/NotFound";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <Router>
        <Suspense fallback={<LazyLoad />}>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
              <Route path={`admin/*`} element={<AdminLayout />} />
              <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/admin/dashboard" />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path={`auth/*`} element={<AuthLayout />} />
          </Routes>
        </Suspense>
      </Router>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

ProtectedRoutes.jsx

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from "js-cookie"

export default function ProtectedRoutes() {

  let userid = Cookies.get("user") == null ? false : true;
  return <div>{userid ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/auth/login" />}</div>;
}
```

The logout function

```
const logout = async () => {
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_LOCAL_URL}/api/v1/auth/logout`
  );

  if (response.data) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
    sessionStorage.removeItem("user");
    localStorage.removeItem("apiEnv");
  }
  return response.data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the problem with cookie.
when you log out, you didn't delete the `user` cookie.

So in the `logout` function, insert this line.

```
if (response.data) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
    sessionStorage.removeItem("user");
    localStorage.removeItem("apiEnv");
    Cookies.remove('user');             // insert
}
```

:)

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: you should make sure to clear your redux state when logging out. So dispatch a logout action that resets your state to its initial state.